# How to overwrite files in a Team Drive using Python?

Tags: python, api, google-drive-api, pydrive

I currently have this code:

```
update_file = drive.CreateFile({
        # 'id':file_path,
        'parents':[{
                        'kind':'drive#fileLink'
                        ,'teamDriveId':'team-drive-file'
                        , 'id': folder_id
                    }
                   ]
                        }   
                        )
    update_file.SetContentFile(file_name)
    update_file.Upload(param={'supportsTeamDrives': True})
```

What this does is only create a duplicate file of the file I wanted to overwrite. What I want to do is to overwrite the file instead. Does anyone know what I can do to overwrite files on a team drive?

Thanks!